# Make link option in theme customizer

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am currently developing my own Wordpress theme. I currently have three buttons in my theme. I want to assign links to these buttons through the Wordpress customiser interface. However, I have no idea how to do this (e.g. which functions to use) Anyone familiar with this?

Since I do not know how to start I did not try anything yet.